# Call a procedure or function in Oracle DB with return = array of UDT from WSO2 DSS

Tags: arrays, oracle, wso2, wso2-data-services-server, user-defined-types

I follow this post[1] as a guide to build an example of query an array of UDT in WSO2 DSS. In the post just query an UDT, my config try to query an UDT array.

I created this in my DB, a dummy PROCEDURE to try this:

```
create or replace
TYPE "LIST_CUSTOMERS" IS TABLE OF customer_t


CREATE OR REPLACE 
PROCEDURE getCustomer2(listcust OUT list_customers) IS 
cust customer_t;
cust2 customer_t;
BEGIN 
listcust := list_customers();
cust := customer_t(1, 'prabath'); 
cust2 := customer_t(2, 'jorge'); 
listcust.extend;
listcust(1) := cust;
listcust.extend;
listcust(2) := cust2;
END;
```

My DS is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data name="UDTSample2">
   <config id="default">
      <property name="org.wso2.ws.dataservice.driver">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
      <property name="org.wso2.ws.dataservice.protocol">jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:DBMB</property>
      <property name="org.wso2.ws.dataservice.user">****</property>
      <property name="org.wso2.ws.dataservice.password">****</property>
   </config>
   <query id="q3" useConfig="default">
      <sql>call getCustomer2(?)</sql>
      <result element="customers">
<element name="customer" arrayName="custArray" column="cust" optional="true"/> 
</result>
      <param name="cust" paramType="ARRAY" sqlType="ARRAY" type="OUT" structType="LIST_CUSTOMERS" />

   </query>
   <operation name="op3">
      <call-query href="q3" />
   </operation>
</data>
```

ant return:

```
<customers xmlns="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
   <customer>{1,prabath}</customer>
   <customer>{2,jorge}</customer>
</customers>
```

but I  want something like this:

```
<customers xmlns="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
    <customer>
        <id>1</id>
        <name>prabath<name>
    </customer>
    <customer>
        <id>2</id>
        <name>Jorge<name>
    </customer>
</customers>
```

How can I accomplish this?

```
[1] http://prabathabey.blogspot.com/2012/05/query-udtsuser-defined-types-with-wso2.html
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether this kind of transformation can be done at DSS level because DSS gives back what it recieves from database. Better use WSO2 esb for this kind of transformation.

Comment: in this case the return it's an object array, and those object are a Oracle UDT. In all wso2 samples, they show the return a UDT object, never an array.

Answer (score 0):

By the moment it's not possible to accomplish this scenario using just DSS. the DS response must be send to the WSO2 ESB to do the corresponding transformation before send the response to the client. A JIRA was created to do this in the future https://wso2.org/jira/browse/DS-1104

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you can use a procedure returning a sys_refcursor. 
It would look like this:

```
PROCEDURE getCustomer_CUR(cur_cust OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) 
l_cust LIST_CUSTOMERS;
IS
-- Retrieve cust list:
getCustomer2(l_cust);

OPEN cur_cust for 
select cast(multiset(select * from TABLE(l_cust)) as customer_t) from dual;
...
END;
```

Then you can do your DSS mapping something like:

```
   <sql>call getCustomer_CUR(?)</sql>
  <result element="customers">
      <element arrayName="custArray" name="Customers">
               <element column="custArray[0]" name="col0" xsdType=.../>
               ...
      </element>
</result>
  <param name="cust" sqlType="ORACLE_REF_CURSOR" type="OUT"/>
```

It is tedious but it works.